# Pandas columns of lists, create multiple columns by iterate (select) each list element of three columns as new columns and rows

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, loops

I have a dataframe of five columns where three of these columns contain lists of multiple values, which are ("Long", "Lat", Time_stamp"). Note that all ("Long", "Lat", Time_stamp") columns as object data-type.
[image: Original dataframe]
Rather than storing multiple values in a cell, I'd like to split these values of the three columns into new three columns with including each lists element, so that each item in these lists gets its own rows (with the same values in all other columns( index  and car_id). So the output I am looking for is as follows :

| index | car_id | Long | Lat | Time_stamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 8919 | 108.99553 | 34.27859 | 1539041301 |
| 0 | 8919 | 108.99552 | 34.27822 | 1539041304 |
| 0 | 8919 | 108.99552 | 34.27786 | 1539041307 |
| 0 | 8919 | 108.99552 | 34.27748 | 1539041310 |
| 1 | 19785 | 108.9665 | 34.20515 | 1539014039 |
| 1 | 19785 | 108.9665 | 34.20543 | 1539014042 |
| 1 | 19785 | 108.9665 | 34.20572 | 1539014046 |
| 1 | 19785 | 108.9665 | 34.20602 | 1539014049 |

And so on.....

Thank you for your help....

Comment: try `pd.concat([df[col].explode() for col in df.columns],axis=1)`

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help, it is a nice and elegant way to solve the problem. Many thanks. @anky

Answer (score 0):

### Assumption

The following code assumes only a fixed number of columns need to be normalized.

### Implementation

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'car_id': [[1], [2]], 'longitudes': [[108.99553, 108.99552], [108.9665]], 'latitudes': [[34.27859, 34.27822, 34.27786], [34.20543, 34.20572]]})

print(df)

pd.DataFrame([car_id, longitude, latitude] for car_id, longitudes, latitudes in df.values for car_id in car_id for longitude in longitudes for latitude in latitudes)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values in a column are in a list you can use explode to distribute each of the values of the list into its own row.

please try

```
              df2.explode('Long').explode('Lat').explode('Time_stamp')
```